# should floated divs have height

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and HTML, I have one problem with regard to height of floated elements:

when I set the height of the "content" div to anything more than or equal to the "main" div height, then the margin top of footer is showing correctly, but as soon as I change the height of content div to auto, margin top of footer is not working. I would really like to know is there any solution which makes the content height auto but respects the margin top of footer. Please help me. I've tried everything: clearfixes of every kind, overflow etc.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
        <div id="main"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>

#container { width:800px; height:auto; background:#000; }
#header { width:800px; height:80px; background:#333; }
#content { width:800px; height:500px; background:#999; }
#main { width:600px; height:500px; background:skyblue; float:right; }
#sidebar { width:200px; height:500px; background:silver; float:left; }
#footer { width:800px; height:80px; background:green; clear:both; margin-top:10px; }
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/bqWS7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `overflow:hidden` Property .

> “overflow: hidden” is often used for the purpose of **float containment**.
>   It can do more special things, however: prevent an element's margins
>   from collapsing with its children and prevent an element from
>   extending “behind” an adjacent floated element.

Source: [The magic of “overflow: hidden”](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)

```
#content{
    width:800px;
    height:auto;
    background:#999;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRk8z/1/)

Comment: Thanks it works and it is very helpful, I actually used overflow:auto; because i needed content to scroll when necessary but it still worked,

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix...here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/739Ue/)

```
#container{width:800px;height:auto;background:#000;}
#header{position:relative;width:800px;height:80px;background:#333;}
#content{position:relative;width:800px;height:500px;background:#999;}
#main{position:relative;width:600px;height:800px;background:skyblue;float:right;margin-bottom: 10px;}
#sidebar{position:relative;width:200px;height:800px;background:silver;float:left;margin-bottom: 10px;}
#footer{position:relative;width:800px;height:80px;background:green;clear:both;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you have added margin to main and sidebar divs thats exactly what i have done now, but I want to add margin to footer without adding any bottom margin to other divs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your set-up is that when you set the `height` of `#container` to `auto`, its height is actually computed to zero. This is because `#container` contains purely floated elements, and they are ignored when computing the height of `#container`.

To fix this, add a clearfix inside `#content` but after any other content. For example:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix { clear: both }
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mzxjs/